# Spring data framework writes to wrong mongodb collection

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Spring data framework inserts data into wrong collection. When I am tying to add `productPropertiesService.add(new ProductProperties(200,100));` this record goes to `Product` collection not `ProductProperties` collection. How to fix it?

My **applicationContext**:

```
...
  <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="mongoDbFactory"
          class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory">
        <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongoFactoryBean" />
        <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="test" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="mongoFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
        <property name="host" value="localhost" />
        <property name="port" value="27017"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
    <mongo:repositories base-package="ee.test.mongo.dao"/>
    <mongo:repositories base-package="mongodb"/>
    ...
```

Class to test insertion:

```
public class MongoDBJDBC {

    public static void main( String args[] ){
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/applicationContext.xml");

        ProductService productService = context.getBean(ProductService.class);
        ProductPropertiesService productPropertiesService = context.getBean(ProductPropertiesService.class);
        productPropertiesService.add(new ProductProperties(200,100));
        }
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
            public class ProductPropertiesService {
                @Autowired
                private ProductPropertiesDao productPropertiesDao;

                public void add(ProductProperties productProperties) {
                    productPropertiesDao.save(productProperties);
                }
             }
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
            public class ProductPropertiesDao {

                @Autowired
                private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

                public void save(ProductProperties productProperties) {
                    mongoOperations.save(productProperties);
                }
```

**UPDATE**
Entity class:

```
@Document(collection = ProductProperties.COLLECTION_NAME)
public class ProductProperties implements Serializable {

    public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "product_properties";
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String property;
    ...
  }
```

Problem solved but as a strange side effect the document is being added to correct collection but extra field being added `"_class" : "ee.test.mongo.model.ProductProperties"`. How to fix it?

Comment: Show us the entity class, and what versions are you using?

Comment: I am using version   2.6.4

Comment: Not just MongoDB, but also Spring and Spring Data.

Comment: Spring `4.1.0.RELEASE` and Spring-Data-mongodb `1.4.0.RELEASE`

Comment: Since different models can be saved to one collection, the `_class` is a helper for Spring Data to identify which model to map this data to. Simply ignore all fields with an underscore (except `_id`, of course)